# Remove or Add an attribute to CoreData at runtime programmatically

Tags: ios, core-data, attributes

I have to create and remove attributes based on an api response in Objective C. 
For example, Now my api response contains fields "**facebook**", "**whatsapp**" and "**viber**". But in future the reponse can add "**youtube**". Based on this response, I have to remove all the attributes and values of an entity "Social", and create Four attributes now and set values. 
How to do that programmatically? Because the default *.xcdatamodeld file cant help me here, right?
Note: My project is in objective C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data model is mutable when the app starts-- you can completely build the model in code, and not use the model editor, for example. But as soon as you load a persistent store file, you **must** treat the model as fixed. Any changes after loading a persistent store will cause crashes. That means any changes would have to happen before calling either `loadPersistentStores(completionHandler:)` or `addPersistentStore(with:completionHandler:)`.

Alexander's suggestion of optional attributes is a good one. If you need the model to be more dynamic, you would need to create a new related entity which would store the service name plus whatever information you need to save about the service. If you did this, your `Social` entity would have a to-many relationship to a new entity called something like `Service`. `Service` would have a string property called `name` that would have values like twitter, facebook, youtube, etc. It would also have whatever other attributes you need to save about the service.

Comment: Yeah, that solution with creating one to-many relationships makes sense! :) But I think there is no reason of building the model in code, since after the first creation of the persistent store it will anyway be immutable until the next app update with the new version of data model to enable lightweight migrations :)

Answer (score 0):

You can **create all 4 fields in advance** and just make them optional and fill them depending on the server response. **But you cannot add new attributes in runtime.** Your `*.xcdatamodeld` file compiles into `*.momd` and it contains all the data to create tables in the DB since **Core Data** by default works with **SQLite** under the hood and it's a relational database management system.

To make attributes optional you should check that.

[image]

And then newly created objects contain `nil` as default values of object properties. So, in your case your **"youtube"** property of `Social` object will be just `nil`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I get that for the "remove attribute" part. But what about adding attribute? any workaround?

Comment: You cannot add new attributes in runtime, all your table's attributes in the database will be created when your database is created. So, if you want to add something in runtime, you can store your JSON as a string and then fetch it and parse. For example, your Social entity can have an attribute jsonAsAString attribute of type string, and then you can fetch it and parse.